# Strange label on middle categoryAxis Kendo UI when using "roundToBaseUnit=false"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, kendo-ui

I am making weather charts with kendo ui in ASP.NET MVC and I found a strange thing on my second categoryAxis.

When I use "roundToBaseUnit(false)" there is a label coming in the middle of my Axis and I don't know how to remove it. This label is always the same as the last one on the chart.

Everything is on this scrennshot :
[link](http://imgbox.com/Gcg363iw)

Here is how is configured my categoryAxis:

```
.CategoryAxis(axis => axis
                          .Date()
                          .Labels(l => l .Format("dddd"))
                          .RoundToBaseUnit(false)
                          .MaxDateGroups(0)
                          .Categories(model => model.Date)
                          .BaseUnit(ChartAxisBaseUnit.Days)
                  )
```

Comment: Heve you configured the base unit? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-categoryAxis.baseUnit

Comment: Yes, it is set to "Days"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating Kendo UI to the latest version.